# geom_rect and legend that shows the width of the rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2

here is a very simple script

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(xmin = c(1, 2.5, 3), xmax = c(2, 3.5, 5), ymin=c(1,1.5, 3), ymax = c(2,2.5,4), size = c(1,1,2), fill = c("red", "orange", "blue"))

p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_rect(data = df, aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, size = factor(size), fill = fill))
p <- p + scale_size_manual(values = c(1,2), guide = guide_legend(keywidth = 4, override.aes = list(colour = "black")))

p
```

This script creates the following chart ...

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve, is to add a legend (guide) that reflects the width of a rectangle! Just 2 simple lines as "legend key" whereas the width of the key is 1 or 2.

I'm stuck, so any hint is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are specifying the xmin/xmax and ymin/ymax, I don't think the size parameter is doing anything here

```
my_dat <- data.frame(xmin = c(1, 2.5, 3), xmax = c(2, 3.5, 5), 
                     ymin=c(1,1.5, 3), ymax = c(2,2.5,4), 
                     size = c(1,1,2), fill = c("red", "orange", "blue"))

# size doesn't do anything for geom_rect. compare this...
ggplot(my_dat) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
                size = factor(size), fill = fill))

# ...and this. same!
ggplot(my_dat) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, 
                fill = fill))

# try geom_linerange

ggplot(my_dat) +
  geom_linerange(aes(x=(xmin+xmax)/2, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, color=fill, 
                     size=factor(size))) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(20, 50)) +
  xlim(1, 5)
```

[image]

Edited to make result closer to your original plot, though this is a bit of an eccentric plot call.

And if you add `+ theme(legend.direction = 'horizontal')`:

[image]